# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Id' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I got this error when trying run my sql query...

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Id' to data type
>   int

```
SELECT *
FROM History
INNER JOIN Header
ON History.Id = Header.docId
```

Please help me :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `Join` condition am sure one column is of `Integer` type and other one is `Varchar` type.

```
ON History.Id = Header.docId
```

since `Int` has higher precedence than `varchar`, `Varchar` column will be implicitly converted to `Int`

So explicitly convert the `Int` column to varchar.

```
ON History.Id = cast(Header.docId as varchar(50))
```

I have considered `Header.docId` as `Int` type if no, then convert `History.Id` to `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

Try casting Id column to INT

```
SELECT *
FROM History
INNER JOIN Header
ON cast(History.Id AS int) = Header.docId
```